# C++ - Is there a way to add fields\methods to a type that was defined with 'typedef'?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef

As titles says, is there a way to do something like:

```
typedef vector<int> ListInt;
string ListInt::GetSomeValue() { //Add method to 'ListInt'
    return "value";
}
int ListInt::SomeField; //Add field\variable to 'ListInt'
```

Without inheritance and etc. (To reduce compilation time)

Sorry for the short message, but I think it's enough.

Comment: You are going to modify an existing type? No, this is not possible in C++. By the way, inheriting from `std::vector` is perhaps a bad idea.

Comment: The customary way of "adding" methods to an existing type is to use free functions. To add fields (i.e. state) you might want to consider subclassing a new type (but that comes with a *big* sack of surprises).

Comment: No. Also, the typedef should be `typedef std::vector<int> ListInt;`.

Comment: it often takes this form: `class ListInt { /* ... */ std::string GetSomeValue() const; private: vector<int> list; };`

Comment: Yes you can!!!!!! If you have guts to modify the headers having definition of std::vector.

Comment: @Justin But I have to re-declare all the methods that vector has. I have big classes to do that to. I think I can't take that option.

Comment: @Anonymous i wouldn't call that 'Guts'

Comment: @MessyCode in some cases, you might expose the vector with an accessor. more often, you realize abstraction is better. often, you only need to wrap a small part of vector's interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//ListInt.h
struct ListInt {
    vector<int> *operator->( );
    vector<int> *operator*( );
    int SomeField;
    string GetSomeValue( );
private:
    vector<int> internalvalue;
};

//ListInt.cpp
vector<int> *ListInt::operator->( ) {
    return &internalvalue;
}
vector<int> *ListInt::operator*( ) {
    return &internalvalue;
}
string ListInt::GetSomeValue( ) {
    return "value";
}
```

Address to `SomeField` as `ListInt::SomeField` and address to `GetSomeValue` as `ListInt::GetSomeValue`.
Example:

```
ListInt listInt;
listInt.SomeField = 3;
listInt.GetSomeValue( ); //Returns 'value'
listInt->push_back(2); //Use `vector<int>`'s fields.
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but: perhaps because this code doesn't satisfy your own requirements? For example, `listInt[0]` won't compile.

Comment: @Vlad Fixed again ,`(*listInt)[0]`'ll do it.

Comment: @DeadMG Kiddin'? Fixed :S. I feel next time I'll not answer my question if you downvote for just `printf`.

Comment: @MessyCode DeadMG never kids about this stuff (btw, i did not downvote)

Comment: @Justin You should focus on the main idea. `printf` it's not the main idea.

Comment: @MessyCode Ignore downvotes, or you'll end up like Don Quixote [tilting at windmills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilting_at_windmills).

Comment: @PeterWood My first user blocked because of this. I don't want to open another user.

Comment: @MessyCode: well, `(*listInt)[0]` is still not the same as just `listInt[0]`. The difference is: for the new operation you have to use `listInt`, for the old ones `*listInt`. This is not the same as you requested in the OP.

Comment: @Vlad I don't care how it'll look\does ,I am developing interpreter that'll do all of that things. Btw if you mean the use of it ,I didn't want it to be `GetSomeValue(listInt)`.

Comment: @MessyCode: Even if the syntax is not *the same*, it is not that hard to get it there (i.e. implement whatever the required interface functions are by forwarding them to the inner vector. Probably more work than you really need though.

Comment: I won't downvote, but recommend next time to define "something like" much more strictly. This solution does not differ drastically from free function or type encapsulation and actually is not "injecting into typedef" in any possible sense. So, please, be precise in your desires.

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун I thought about just changing the syntax `GetSomeValue(listInt)` To `listInt.GetSomeValue()`. Not really inject ,sorry. About the first part ,I mentioned what I wanted in the title ,after the second line it's was just my example.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The vector was just an example. In my classes I need all of the function. Not just few methods like in `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

This is solved in languages I am aware of using either [Uniform Function Call Syntax](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/uniform-function-call-syntax/232700394) or run-time type modification. None of those is supported by C++, so, no, I think you are out of options here. There are plenty of "close" solutions, like inheritance or free functions or encapsulating type - but none exactly like you have requested.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to add fields/methods to a type that was defined with 'typedef'?

The first thing that needs answering is what `typedef` really means. A `typedef` creates an *alias* for an existing type, but it does *not* create a new type. After the `typedef` the new name will refer exactly to the same type as the original, and both names can be used interchangeably in *most* contexts <sup>*</sup>.

Once that is clear, the answer seems obvious: you cannot add or remove any feature from the `typedef` alias, since it refers to exactly the other type. There are no two types, only one: the original.

---

<sup>*</sup> The original type, and the alias created through a `typedef` are not 100% equivalent, although there are very few differences. In particular, the name of the original type (assuming it is user defined, which `std::vector<X>` is) resides in a different identifier space than functions, variables or `typedef` aliases. The `typedef` name is not the name of a type, it is an alias to a type. The following code shows one of the differences:

```
struct A {};
typedef A B;
struct A a;      // creates a variable `a` of type `A`
//struct B b;    // error, `B` is a typedef, not a `struct`
```

Some of the most notable differences are only clear when compiling multiple translation units: `typedef` aliases are *always* internal to the translation unit. No symbols generated in the object file will refer to a `typedef`. The compiler will resolve the `typedef` for the actual type and all symbols and name mangling will be perform as if the *real* type was used.

Comment: Yeah I knew about the alias then I wanted another alias ,adding methods that I'll press dot and it'll show me the 'aliased' methods or even deconstruct that'll after delete\scope.

Comment: @MessyCode: Either it is an alias or it is a different type, you cannot have an alias that is different than the aliased element.

Comment: I think I really got what `typedef` does. It's just like `#define` ,you can't use it like a normal function it does like copy and paste. Really thanks.